# Where is the best place to ask a subjective programming question?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

I have a question that is a mix of system management, security and the Python language. In short, I want to ask the best way to maintain a production Python environment. This is something hundreds (if not thousands) of SO users deal with on a daily basis, but I am concerned that best-practices questions are routinely rounded up and shot if they're not precisely on-topic. I know, I regularly pull the trigger on Ask Ubuntu.

Note: I don't think this is unanswerable. There is undoubtedly at least one best way of doing what I'm asking but such a question might elicit lots of suggestions.

So where would you ask this sort of question? SO? SF? Security.SE? Programmers.SE? Or is it just too flabby for Stack Exchange?

**Edit:** [I have posted on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199948/how-can-i-keep-a-production-python-environment-secure) on the recommendations in the comments. We'll see how things go.

Comment: Programmers, but you'll have to ask it just right.  Good Luck.

Comment: Questions like this need to be seriously looked at.  A typical new user / user in general will not do what @Oli has done.  And that is what steers people away from the sites.

Comment: Does it have to be subjective? That is, do you have to ask for the "best way"? Surely you tried something and found it lacked somehow. Surely you situation has some specifics. That's no guarantee it will do any better, but it would improve the likelihood.

Comment: You may find the guidelines in [this SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) helpful.

Comment: @Bart I currently have *a way* but it isn't nearly good enough. I can certainly enumerate the current process in the question and ask for improvements on it but I feel that's just making it even more subjective ;)